# Is there any guarantee about the evaluation order within a pattern match?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, strictness

The following

```
(&&) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
False && _ = False
True && False = False
True && True = True
```

has the desired short-circuit property `False && undefined ≡ False`. The first clause, which is non-strict in the right argument, is guaranteed to be checked before anything else is tried.

Apparently, it still works if I change the order and even uncurry the function

```
both :: (Bool,Bool) -> Bool
both (True,False) = False
both (True, True) = True
both (False, _) = False

Prelude> both (False, undefined)
False
```

but is this actually guaranteed by the standard? Unlike with the order of clauses, the order of evaluation of the patterns is not so clear here. Can I actually be sure that matching `(True,False)` will be aborted as soon as `(False,_)` is determined, before the snd element is evaluated at all?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed that evaluating the expression `both (False, undefined)` will not diverge since matching on data constructors is guaranteed to match left-to-right against the components of the constructor and the pattern fails as soon as some sub-pattern fails. Since the first element of the tuple is `False`, the pattern will fail for both `(True, ...)` branches as soon as the first element fails to match.

Per the [Haskell 2010 Report, section 3.17.2](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-600003.17.2), which gives an informal semantics of pattern matching:

> 5. Matching the pattern *con pat1 … patn* against a value, where *con* is a constructor defined by data, depends on the value:
>
>    - If the value is of the form *con v1 … vn*, sub-patterns are matched left-to-right against the components of the data value; if all matches succeed, the overall match succeeds; the first to fail or diverge causes the overall match to fail or diverge, respectively.
>    - If the value is of the form *con′ v1 … vm*, where con is a different constructor to *con′*, the match fails.
>    - If the value is ⊥, the match diverges.

Since the tuple syntax is just a special-case syntactic sugar for a data constructor, the above applies.

For a fuller treatment of pattern matching, see [section 3.17.3 of the Haskell 2010 Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-610003.17.3), which gives a formal semantics of pattern matching (specifically, figure 3.2 pertains to this question).

Another resource of interest is the paper [Pattern-driven Reduction in Haskell](http://programatica.cs.pdx.edu/P/journal-wrs2002.pdf) which specifies the semantics as an interpreter (written in Haskell) of an abstract syntax representation of Haskell's concrete syntax (the function `mP` in figure 3, page 7 is relevant to the question).